# Java: Difference between the setPreferredSize() and setSize() methods in components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

What is the main difference between `setSize()` and `setPreferredSize()`. Sometimes I used [`setSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29), sometimes [`setPreferredSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29), sometimes one does what I want, sometimes the other.

What call should I use for `JFrame`s and `JPanel`s?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Usage depends on whether the component's parent has a layout manager or not.

- `setSize()` -- use when a parent layout manager does not exist;
- `setPreferredSize()` (also its related `setMinimumSize` and `setMaximumSize`) -- use when a parent layout manager exists.

The `setSize()` method probably won't do anything if the component's parent is using a layout manager; the places this will typically have an effect would be on top-level components (`JFrame`s and `JWindow`s) and things that are inside of scrolled panes.  You also must call `setSize()` if you've got components inside a parent without a layout manager.

Generally, `setPreferredSize()` will lay out the components as expected if a layout manager is present; most layout managers work by getting the preferred (as well as minimum and maximum) sizes of their components, then using `setSize()` and `setLocation()` to position those components according to the layout's rules.

For example, a `BorderLayout` tries to make the bounds of its "north" region equal to the preferred size of its north component---they may end up larger or smaller than that, depending on the size of the `JFrame`, the size of the other components in the layout, and so on.

Comment: I thought a component was using a layout manager by default (BorderLayout?), so if I don't explicitly set a layout manager does that mean I should use setSize() instead of setPreferredSize()?

Comment: I believe JPanels use BorderLayout by default, but JComponent has no default layout.  Most of the time, you're better off setting a layout manager if you'll be adding something instead of using setSize().

Comment: My recommendation is to always use a layout manager.  SetSize() should be thought of as something that the layout manager calls - not something that you call.

Comment: @Sbodd - JPanels have a FlowLayout by default. JFrame.getContentPane() has a BorderLayout by default.

Comment: By the way one useful fact is that if you e.g. setPreferredSize() of a Frame to something very wide, e.g. 1920 pixels, then someone running in e.g. 1600 resolution will still receive a window that "fits their screen". That's the question I came here looking for, and since I couldn't find the explicit answer on SO I "took one for the team" and tested it manually :) -- so anyway thought I'd at least mention that here.

Answer (score 11):

`setSize()` or `setBounds()` can be used when no layout manager is being used.

However, if you are using a layout manager you can provide hints to the layout manager using the `setXXXSize()` methods like `setPreferredSize()` and `setMinimumSize()` etc.

And be sure that the component's container uses a layout manager that respects the requested size. The `FlowLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, and `SpringLayout` managers use the component's preferred size (the latter two depending on the constraints you set), but `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout` usually don't.If you specify new size hints for a component that's already visible, you need to invoke the revalidate method on it to make sure that its containment hierarchy is laid out again. Then invoke the repaint method.

Answer (score 7):

`setSize` will resize the component to the specified size.

`setPreferredSize` sets the preferred size.  The component may not actually be this size depending on the size of the container it's in, or if the user re-sized the component manually.

Comment: Can you show a full example of setPreferredSize(...). I  think that this would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

IIRC ...

`setSize` sets the size of the component.

`setPreferredSize` sets the preferred size. 
The Layoutmanager will try to arrange that much space for your component.

It depends on whether you're using a layout manager or not ...

Comment: and what if I add two jpanels to a jframe without specifying a layout manager explicitly for the jframe? what method should i used to set the size of the jpanels?

Comment: Content panes use BorderLayout by default (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). So the JFrame's contentpane has a LayoutManager, so setPreferredSize _should_ work ..

Comment: Sounds good, that means I should use setSize for the JFrame and setPreferredSize for the components inside

Comment: You would generally use frame.pack() to take advantage of the calculated preferred size of all the child components. Otherwise if you just randomly use frame.setSize(), then the components added to the content pane will expand/contract to fit the space available, which means the preferred size of each component may be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact that `setSize()` should be used in the absence of a layout manager, and `setPreferredSize()` - when there is no layout manager, there is another difference. 1 takes two numbers in the parameters, and `setPreferredSize()` takes an object of class `java.awt.Dimension`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.setSize(200,300); //numbers
frame.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200,300)); //an object of java.awt.Dimension
```