# How can I resize a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtextfield

How can I resize a JTextField?

Comment: I, and apparently 1910 others, do not see why this question was closed as not constructive. It doesn't need to be a super long question to be constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the Javadoc, you'll see that [JTextField](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) derives from [Component](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), and that has a [setSize()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) method. If you don't have a layout manager then that's of use.

If you *do* have a layout manager, then [setPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)/`setMinimumSize()`/`setMaximumSize()` is the way to go. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783880/12960) for more details.

Comment: Layout managers will call setSize() and override your size.  It is better to use setPreferredSize(), setMinimumSize(), and setMaximumSize().

Comment: @JayAskren - noted and amended. Thx

Comment: actually, you shouldn't call setXXSize _ever_, some reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657 Instead, choose a LayoutManager that fits your need @JayAskren

Comment: @Kleopatra That is fair.  If you use one of the third party layout manager's mentioned, you may not need to use setXXXSize().  If you use standard Java layout managers, especially GridBagLayout, you can't get away without using setXXXSize().  Either way, you should never call setSize().

Answer (score 4):

The [jtextfield tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) tells you about setColumns(), which might be what you want. Otherwise, you might need to learn about how to use layout managers - here's a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).