# How can I resize a Swing text field?

Tags: java, textfield, jtextfield

I wrote the code below:

```
public class Information extends JFrame{
private JComboBox comboBox1;
private JComboBox comboBox2;
private JTextField textField[];
private JTextField jtextField;
private JLabel label[];

public Information()
{
    setLayout(new flowlayout());
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)//textfield
    {
        textField = new JTextField[20];
        box.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,5)));
        textField[i] = new JTextField(2);

        textField[i].setAlignmentX(2f);
        textField[i].setAlignmentY(2f);

        box.add(textField[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++ )//lable
    {

    }
    add(box);
}
}
```

I want that text field showed in my favorite size, but it fills the whole screen.

I used

```
 textField[i].setAlignmentX(2f);
 textField[i].setAlignmentY(2f);
```

and `setcolum()`, but it didn't resize the text field. How can I decrease my text fields' sizes?

I use from

```
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 70));
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
```

their resize the textfield but change it's location but i don't want to change their

location.is there any manner than i change textfield position?

i use from setlocation but it didn't work!!.

Comment: see also: [Need help! how can i resize a JTextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442111/need-help-how-can-i-resize-a-jtextfield)

Answer (score 4):

use [setPreferredSize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)

also [setMinimumSize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29), [setMaximumSize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMaximumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)

Comment: Interesting... see [Difference between the setPreferredSize() and setSize() methods in components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-componen) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use `setBounds` which will take a width and height as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The `setAlignment` methods change the alignment of a component in its container, not the component's actual size. I think you're looking for `JTextField`'s [`setColumns()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns%28int%29). There's always the inherited [`setSize()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29), too.

Comment: Wait, what are you setting it on? Are you setting it on the array? That shouldn't even compile, let alone actually resize a specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Try [setPreferredSize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29), this (along with setMinimum/MaximumSize()) tend to be used by a lot of [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) including FlowLayout to appropriately size a container's components.

Also, as a side note, looks like you're re-creating your array of JTextAreas each iteration in that for loop, so only textField[19] would exist...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to Set a specific size for your textfield.
To do this :
Firstly set the layout as null using the object of Information class

```
information.setLayout(null);
```

And set the bounds of the JTextField using setBounds method :

```
textField.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
```