# Java Applet painting clips to [195,200] despite resize

Tags: java, eclipse, canvas, applet, clip

### Intention

I have a `java.applet.Applet` subclass `MyApplet` with a `java.awt.Canvas` subclass `MyCanvas` added to it.

My code changes the size of `MyApplet` to `new Dimension(600,400)` and changes the size of `MyCanvas` to match.

When `MyCanvas` is `paint`ed, it should

1. fill its **whole area** with **red**
2. draw a **blue circle** of width 300 and height 300.

### Problem

Instead (when run as a Java Applet from Eclipse), the paint of `MyCanvas` clips to a far smaller area than 600,400 (I measured it to be 195,200) even though `MyApplet` resizes correctly. [This is what it looks like.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/196227/MyAppletContents.png)

[image]

The printouts are OK too -- see bottom of post.

### Code

This is my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyApplet extends Applet {

    Canvas mainCanvas;

    public void init() {

        // Set the size of the applet
        setSize(600, 400);

        // Print dimensions
        System.out.println("Applet dimensions: " + getSize());

        // Make a canvas with the same sizes as this applet
        mainCanvas = new MyCanvas(getWidth(), getHeight());
        add(mainCanvas);
    }

    public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

        public MyCanvas(int w, int h) {

            setSize(w, h);

            System.out.println("Canvas dimensions: " + getSize());
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            System.out.println("Canvas dimensions when painting: " + getSize());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

### Printouts

It produces the following printout:

```
Applet dimensions: java.awt.Dimension[width=600,height=400]
Canvas dimensions: java.awt.Dimension[width=600,height=400]
Canvas dimensions when painting: java.awt.Dimension[width=600,height=400]
Canvas dimensions when painting: java.awt.Dimension[width=600,height=400]
```

The sizes are correct throughout!

### Attempted solutions

- I tried `setBounds()` instead of `setSize()` both in `MyApplet` and `MyCanvas` just in case the position was offset toward the top-left. This just shifted the circle -- the clip persisted.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "My code changes the size of `MyApplet`.."  If you can find one browser that resizes an applet according to Java code, I'll find two that won't.

Comment: I know. This is for testing. I don't want to re-JAR my code and open a browser every time I test my applet. Even if I did bother, I couldn't use the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it!

The **environment** that Eclipse provides to Applets is **by default** configured to have size 200, 200. All painting clips to this area unless the **default Run Configuration** is changed.

This can be done as follows:

1. Right-click the root folder of your applet in the *Package* view
2. Select *Run As...* -> *Run Configurations...*
3. Click the *Parameters* tab
4. Change *Width* and *Height* fields as required.

Answer (score 3):

In the first line of your init put this:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
```

This will cause your canvas to take up all the space of your applet.

Comment: No change. I'm starting to think this is a problem with Eclipse's applet environment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be calling `setPreferredSize` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-componen) explains the differences

Comment: `setPreferredSize` makes it worse -- now `MyApplet` resizes to the size of the small clip! Also, the thread you linked to says to use `setSize` over `setPreferredSize` when I have no set layout manager, which is the case here.

Comment: @Aku: "..I have no set layout manager.." You may not have *set* one, but there is a *default.*  Prove it by putting this as the first line in the `init()` method: `System.out.println(getLayout());`.