# JGraph AWT EventQueue exception on paint (with multithreading)

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, awt, paint

#### Situation

I have a visualisation using [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html). The graph is updated by a different thread to that which instantiates the Visualisation.

#### Expected Behaviour

The graph should be updated by various worker threads. The function that the threads call to update the graph is `syncronized`, so the worker threads will not causes concurrency issues between themselves.

#### Actual Behaviour

There is (*ocassionally*) an exception thrown in the AWT-EventQueue thread when painting. Sometimes it's a null pointer, sometimes it's an index out of bounds. Here's a stack trace:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.mxgraph.shape.mxConnectorShape.translatePoint(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.shape.mxConnectorShape.paintShape(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.canvas.mxGraphics2DCanvas.drawCell(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph.drawState(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawCell(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawChildren(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawCell(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawChildren(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawCell(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawChildren(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawCell(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawFromRootCell(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.drawGraph(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
>       at com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent$mxGraphControl.paint(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:866)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
>       at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:764)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5138)
>       at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:302)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1188)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5086)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4896)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:783)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:735)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:58)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1593)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:647)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:617)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

It doesn't seem to adversely affect the running of the application. A new AWT-EventQueue spawns, which will at some stage inevitably encounter the same problem.

#### Cause

I think it must caused by updating the graph in a separate thread to the one that the JFrame is instantiated in. The things that need to be drawn are being changed whilst the paint method is trying to draw them.

#### Question

How do I go about working around this problem? Can I somehow synchronize the paint method with the method that updates the graph?

#### Visualisation Code

```
package ui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.mxgraph.layout.mxOrganicLayout;
import com.mxgraph.layout.mxStackLayout;
import com.mxgraph.model.mxCell;
import com.mxgraph.model.mxGraphModel;
import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;

import core.Container;
import core.Node;
import core.WarehouseGraph;

public class Visualisation extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8356615097419123193L;
    private mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    mxOrganicLayout graphlayout = new mxOrganicLayout(graph);
    mxStackLayout containerLayout = new mxStackLayout(graph, true, 10);

    public Visualisation(WarehouseGraph model){
        super("Warehouse Simulator");

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 600);

        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        try{
            for(Node node : model.getNodes().values()){
                mxCell cell = (mxCell)graph.insertVertex(parent, node.getId(), node.getId(), 0, 0, 60, 30);

                Object prev = null;
                for(Container container : node.getContainers()){
                    Object newCont = graph.insertVertex(cell, container.getId(), container.getId(), 0, 0, 60, 20);
                    if(prev != null) graph.insertEdge(cell, null, null, prev, newCont);
                    prev = newCont;
                }
            }

            for(Node node : model.getNodes().values()){
                for(Node toNode : node.getDownstreamNodes()){
                    Object fromCell = ((mxGraphModel)graph.getModel()).getCell(node.getId());
                    Object toCell = ((mxGraphModel)graph.getModel()).getCell(toNode.getId());
                    graph.insertEdge(parent, null, null, fromCell, toCell);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }

        graphlayout.execute(parent);

        Object[] nodes = mxGraphModel.getChildVertices(graph.getModel(), parent);
        for(Object cell : nodes){
            containerLayout.execute(cell);
            graph.updateCellSize(cell);
        }


        mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
        getContentPane().add(graphComponent);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    //CALLED FROM SYNCHRONIZED FUNCTION
    public void moveContainer(Container container, Node to){
        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        mxCell toCell = (mxCell)((mxGraphModel)graph.getModel()).getCell(to.getId());
        mxCell containerCell = (mxCell)((mxGraphModel)graph.getModel()).getCell(container.getId());
        mxCell fromCell = (mxCell)containerCell.getParent();

        try{
            Object[] edges = mxGraphModel.getEdges(graph.getModel(), containerCell);
            graph.removeCells(edges);

            containerCell.removeFromParent();

            graph.addCell(containerCell, toCell);

            Object[] containers = mxGraphModel.getChildVertices(graph.getModel(), toCell);
            if(containers.length >= 2)
                graph.insertEdge(toCell, null, null, containerCell, containers[containers.length-2]);
            containerLayout.execute(toCell);
            containerLayout.execute(fromCell);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Controller Code

```
package core;
import serialisation.JsonUtil;
import ui.Visualisation;

public class Controller{
    private WarehouseGraph graph;
    Visualisation viz;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Controller.getInstance();
    }

    private Controller(){
        graph = JsonUtil.initFromJson(); //graph has many worker threads running which can call containerMoved
        viz = new Visualisation(graph);
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder{
        private static final Controller INSTANCE = new Controller();
    }

    public static Controller getInstance(){
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public synchronized void containerMoved(Container container, Node from, Node to){
        viz.moveContainer(container, to);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not answer to your question, just some notice for your concept.

1. Can you show us your `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` methods? I am hoping that there is something that looks like:

   public static void main(String[] args) {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

   ```
           public void run() {
               Visualisation vis = new Visualisation();
           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. `this.setSize(800, 600);` should be `this.setpreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));`
3. Then add `this.pack();` before last line (`this.setVisible(true);`)

EDIT:

1. What type of Components returns `mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);` because if is custom Components based on JPanel then

`getContentPane().add(graphComponent);` should be `add(graphComponent);`

1. All input from backGround thread/task must be wrapped into [invokeLater()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). If it is flickering or freezing, then you have to look for `invokeAndWait()`. Personally I hate `invokeAndWait()` exists there, but for this method I can't give you some correct suggestions. Or:
2. If you'll run your task on some periodical bases, then you have to look for Runnable (output must be wrapped into invokeLater) or for [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: 1: It's in the Controller class. It just instantiates the Controller singleton, which in turn initialises the Visualiser. It doesn't do `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` though. What does that do?

Comment: 2: Shouldn't you do `setSize` on top level components (those without a layout manager) as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-componen)?

Comment: 3: Oh, pack does something funky in conjunction with `setPrefferedSize`?

Comment: Many thanks. It sounds like invokeLater on the worker threads should address my issue. I'll have a play around with it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: to your add1) don't create lots of JFrames on Runtime/fly, create only one JFrame and other top-level containers would be JDialog or JWindow(undecorated container), create only one-two JDialog or JWindow and reuse these top-level containers by removeAll();, that avoids memory lack and another unexpected errors came from AWT or Swing,

Comment: to your add2) together with add3) that depends if childs has harcoded size too, if not and if top-level containers occupated only one Container, then set PrefferedSize to its child(s) and used LayoutManagers is in this case BorderLaoyut.CENTER by default

Comment: I don't know somthing about mxgraph, but don't forget that there still exists `invokeAndWait()` and on most of cases better waiting ... as calculated with consequencial `invokeLater()`

Comment: It seems that wrapping `vis.moveContainer` in `invokeAndWait` does the trick. I've also changed the size assignment. Thanks for your tips!

Comment: @Peter Mortensen you have to remove dot, doubledot etc... before code block, otherwise first code line is oout of hightlighter