# Alignment in GridBagLayout (applet)

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, gridbaglayout

I have a problem with GridBagLayout. My components doesnt want to look like i want ;) I want to make a layout like this:

[image]

I wrote a code:

```
    JTextField first = new JTextField();
    ...
    add(third, c);
```

Results look like this, which is "almost" good ;]

[image]

Do you know maybe, how to customize it?

Thanks in advance,
Marcin

// Edit

Hey, i solved a problem with MigLayout (thanks to mKorbel).
Code looks like this (to remove tracking lines, remove debug from constructor):

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("debug"));
add(new JPanel(), "height 200:75%:10000, width 200:75%:10000");
add(new JPanel(), "height 200:75%:10000, width 50:25%:10000, wrap");
add(new JPanel(), "height 50:25%:10000, width 100%, span");
```

(ps if u dont want to make upper bound (10000), you can write hmin x, hmax y ... I dont need it ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `Image` talking about [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), you have to read [BorderLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), then maybe there no reason thinking and implementing [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Good choice; a nested `Box Layout` works well for components in the upper, right pane.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look. But its possible to set percentage size there? Or row/col span?

Comment: no directly isn't possible, then you have look back to GridBagLayout or use todays MigLaoyut, this [code could be help you with GridBagLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9668020/714968)