# JFrame fixed width

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Is it possible to set fixed width for JFrame? At least the following code isn't working:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public final class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(500, 500);
                f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 0));
                f.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The minimum setting is working but the maximum is not.

Comment: for BorderLayout (implemented in API) isn't possible to set MaximumSize,

Comment: Why? See also this cautionary [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513) regarding usability.

Comment: You could use `f.setResizable(false);`

Answer (score 20):

Use   `f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));` in your code.
  And definitely read this post : [Java: Difference between the setPreferredSize() and setSize() methods in components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783793/544983)
  And to prevent your frame growing or shrinking use `f.setResizable(false);`

Answer (score 2):

Set size then write:

```
JFrame.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the maximum to the value you want to specify. 
Depending... the maximum for screen size
or our own value instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Rectangle rc = f.getBounds();
rc.width = 500; //set max width
rc.height = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // set max height
f.setMaximizedBounds(rc);
```

Hope it works on you