# How to resize jdialog buttons?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jbutton, jdialog

Here's the code:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(findArray, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
pane.setOptions(new Object[]{findPreviousButton, findNextButton});
final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(myJFrame, "Find");
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

findArray consists of JLabel findLabel and JTextField findField. myJFrame is the JFrame. findPreviousButton and findNextButton are the two JButtons I am replacing the default "OK" and "Cancel" buttons with. The both have custom icons and no text. The JDialog window is making their icons a certain size making them look pixelated. How do I resize the buttons so that the width is 60 and the height is 30? The method .setSize(int, int) doesn't work and neither does .setBounds(int, int, int, int)

Comment: `The JDialog window is making their icons a certain size making them look pixelated.` - Works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. The buttons are the size of the icons plus the standard button padding.

Comment: I'm sorry your right, I tried comparing them closer and they are the same size, the picture just is less quality :/ that's embarassing

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the button margins should help:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)

Comment: Thanks for trying, that's not what I need though

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use `.setPreferredSize()` instead of `.setSize()`.  Usually when I want to override a component's natural size (meaning how it's laid out by whatever layout manager I'm using), I'll use that along with setting the minimum size as well. If a layout manager is modifying the component's natural size, the `preferredSize()` might be a better option.  There's a good stackoverflow discussion about the differences here:

[Java: Difference between the setPreferredSize() and setSize() methods in components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone)

Comment: That helped but it still didn't re-size the icon, just cropped it.