# Set JPanel's size doesn't depend on JFrame 's size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

My project have an JPanel and JFrame, (JPanel in JFrame).
I set  JFrame ' s size is (400,400). And the size of JPanel is (150,150). I add JPanel to JFrame and run it, when it displayed, the size of JPanel not is 150, it's size is same the size of JFrame. I don't know how to fix it :(

How to set JPanel's size doesn't depend on JFrame 's size?

Here my code:

```
public class Draw_JPanel extends JFrame{
Load_image panel_im = new Load_image();
public Draw_JPanel()
{       
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.add(panel_im);
    }   
public static void main(String[] args){
    Draw_JPanel abc = new Draw_JPanel();

    abc.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and my Load_image class:

```
public class Load_image extends JPanel{
public Load_image()
{
    setSize(30,30);     
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
}
```

Comment: How you add your panel to frame? I think problem with layout, show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add your panel directly to frame which has **BorderLayout** as default , it resizes your panel. Try to use **this.getContentPane().add(panel_im);** instead of **this.add(panel_im);** , because contentPane has  flowLayout as default.  Also read more about **LayoutManager** .[tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Also use **setPreferedSize()** instead of **setSize()** ([difference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone))