# How to create a scrollable Java Box?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, box, scrollpane

I have a Box (verticalBox) in a panel, with checkboxes inside, and i would to do it scrollable.

I tried with

```
Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
JScrollPane scrollArea = new JScrollPane(box,  
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

panel = new JPanel(); 
panel.add(scrollArea); 
add(aggiuntaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I can see the Box in the frame, but i cannot scroll it. How can i do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it the other way round. To make a component scrollable, you have to enclose it **inside** a `JScrollPane`.

> ```
> panel.add(scrollArea);
> ```

should be:

```
scrollPanel.add(panel);
```

Additionally (as mentioned in the comments by @Gorbels) you will need to set  dimensions on the `JScrollPane` before adding it to the containing component:

```
scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

using preferredSize delegates layouting to the layout manager, you may just as well use `setSize()` though there is some differences as outlined [in this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783793/1803692)

Comment: Additionally, it defaults to zero on the dimensions, so if no dimensions are established it won't show the scrollbar even with the policy set to  `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`. You need to set preferred dimensions on at least the `JScrollPane` (if not the `JPanel`).

Comment: @Gorbles thanks for picking that up, I default to setting sizes on anything I create so I overlooked that :)

Comment: Thank you guys! I did like Vogel said, but now I can't see the panels, I only see the vertical scrollbar

Comment: Well the problem in your code that you didn't post. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.