# Java: Changing preferredSize()

Tags: java, resize, jcomponent, preferredsize

How do you change the preferredSize() of a java program, after setVisible()? For example, you have a program that is 100x200, but when you click a button it changes to something else like 300x100.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you have probably to call the repaint() method

Comment: @RenéWinkler already tried that, along with revalidate(), neither worked

Comment: How do you setting size to 100x200? Do you talking about size of a `JFrame`.

Comment: @Reşit Dönük yes, I would like to change the size of the JFrame to a different size, after I called setVisible(true)

Comment: `setSize()` should be work.

Comment: @ReşitDönük ok, that worked, but why did that work and `setPreferredSize()` didn't?

Comment: Becasue they are different methods. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone) for more information.

Comment: @ReşitDönük Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you called setVisible method like this

```
new MyWindow().setVisible(true);
```

And your button's click event name is myButtonActionPerformed, then this code will work:

```
private void myButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
     setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 100));
}
```