# Image not being displayed in jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jpeg, imageicon

So I'm trying to display an image, in a jPanel, within a jFrame.

(I suppose it's that way you display a JPEG/PNG in a jFrame)
Here's what I'm doing:

In the constructor of the jFrame, I download the image, create an ImageIcon, and a jLabel dynamically (set the icon), and insert it in a jPanel.

I have previously created the jPanel with NetBeans IDE, on which *jPanelImage* is defined in the *initComponents()*.

If I go through the code with the debugger, he downloads the image propery without throwing any exceptions.

It also runs the code properly without any problem.

But my jFrame continues empty.
Here's the code:

```
    public TransmissionFrame() {
        initComponents();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Java Technology Dive Log");
    ImageIcon image = null;
    try {
        image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/6mbHZRU.png")));
    } catch(MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } 
    label.setIcon(image);
    jPanelImage.add(label);
    jPanelImage.validate();
}
```

But my jFrame and the jPanel are still empty, why?

Comment: Are you adding your jPanelImage to your JFrame?

Comment: Yes, I statically created it with NetBeans

Comment: You'll want to move your initialization of label and addition of the label into the try catch block. I would also move the JLabel declaration itself in there and try JLabel label = new JLabel(image); Then add label to the panel.

Comment: I go through the try block with the debugger, and I don't get any exceptions, but I tried what you said, and I get the same results

Comment: Please post an [mcve]...it is tough to pin down what the exact problem is without guessing

Comment: I've edited the post, and clearified some situations.
Sorry, please help me out!
Thanks

Comment: Where is `jPanelImage` added to the content pane of a JFrame? Again, an [mcve] would be very useful

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c4750c359e5145dbc106b6dff0e70d77) a working example of working with JLabels as images.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob for the example, but I tried it and I get exactly the same result. An empty jFrame again

Comment: Did you try just that or did you adapt that to what you had before?

Comment: I adapted, but my frame hadn't basically any code ...

Comment: I removed the jPanelImage

Comment: I think your panel isn't being added to your JFrame. Make sure your JFrame is calling getContentPane().add(panel). You can also remove the panel.validate(), as you won't need that.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant or not, but I'm starting the frame from a process like this

Comment: TransmissionFrame frame = new TransmissionFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122544/discussion-between-jacob-and-firecat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update, assigning a layout to your JPanel could be the solution

```
 public TransmissionFrame() {
        initComponents();

        init();
    }

 private void init() {
JLabel label = new JLabel("Java Technology Dive Log");
ImageIcon image = null;
try {
    image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/6mbHZRU.png")));
} catch(MalformedURLException mue) {
    mue.printStackTrace();
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} 
label.setIcon(image);
jPanelImage.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
jPanelImage.add(label);

}
```

Comment: `size of the panel ` setSize won't do anything if the the Container uses a LayoutManager, and a LayoutManager should size the JLabel containing `Icon` appropriately.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone

Answer (score 0):

```
jPanelImage.setVisibility(true);
```