# Java GUI Logic - Not understanding adding to JFrame

Tags: java

I have a pretty straight forward question. Can some please please explain to me why the following JFrame is not showing Hello (100,100 pixels on the left side of the screen and World (100,100 pixels) on the right side of the screen since I am using border layout.

- I created a JFrame
- Assigned it a layout of borderlayout
- Created 2 panels with 2 labels and assigned the panels to be aligned left and right.
- added the panels to the JFrame
- Displayed the JFrame

What am I missing?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(600, 500);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setVisible(true);

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Hello");
label1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
label1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
panel1.add(label1,BorderLayout.LINE_START);

frame.add(panel1);

JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("World");
label2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
label2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
panel2.add(label2,BorderLayout.LINE_END);

frame.add(panel2);
```

Comment: Since your `frame` is managed as a `BorderLayout` you'll want to specify where in the frame `panel1` and `panel2` go. The way you have it, the labels are placed in the panels as if the panels are a `BorderLayout` rather than the frame.

Comment: Doesn't `add(component, START_LINE/END_LINE) ` specify where `panel1` and `panel2` go? i.e one to left and one to the right?

Comment: It adds to the component `add` is called from (in your case `panel1.add(label1, LINE_START)` would add `label1` to `panel1` at `LINE_START`, but only if `panel1` used `BorderLayout`. You want to add to `frame` with the `BorderLayout` constraints since `frame` has the `BorderLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the Layout-Constraints on the wrong panel.

Instead of `panel2.add(label2,BorderLayout.LINE_END);` it should be `panel2.add(label2)` and instead of `frame.add(panel2);` it should be `frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);`.

Same for `panel1`.

Comment: Thanks so much. That makes sense. Why when I set the preferred size of the panel does it not set?

Comment: you're welcome!
that's part of another question already explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone

Comment: That just explains the difference between two methods, not why the width will set, but the height will not.

Comment: that's true, sorry. if you take a look at the javadoc for `BorderLayout` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html you can see that it stretches some contents: `The components are laid out according to their preferred sizes and the constraints of the container's size. The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally; the EAST and WEST components may be stretched vertically; the CENTER component may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left over.`