# What is the difference between getWidth()/getHeight(), and getPreferredSize().width/height?

Tags: java, user-interface, dimension, preferredsize

I'm trying to paint a keyboard with keys that are dynamically resizing when the JFrame is resized. Also, the keys can be in different size.

I have a panel which has its layout set to `BorderLayout`. In the center I put a panel which has its layout set to `GridLayout(5,1)`.

Each row of the grid is a `JPanel` with `FlowLayout`. In each of the rows I'm calculating each button and set its preferred size by calling the `setPreferredSize` method.

When running the program I see only some buttons in a weird appearance. When I'm checking the row panels with `getWidth()/getHeight()` and with `getPreferredSize().width/height`, I'm getting different values: For `getPrefereedSize().width` , I'm getting the width that I really set, but for `getWidth()` I'm getting a significantly lower value.

Is there a difference between both methods, `getWidth()` and `getPreferredSize().width`?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the methods already? :)

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem EVERY time you ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(There is a counterpart of this question: [Java: Difference between the setPreferredSize() and setSize() methods in components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783793/3182664). And there are some other questions regarding `getSize()` and `getPreferredSize()`, but I didn't find one that could be considered as a duplicate. So here we go...)</sup>

A component in Swing usually has a *preferred size*. This is the size that is returned when calling the [`getPreferredSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getPreferredSize--) method. It is the size that the component would "like" to have, in order to be displayed properly. For example, a `JLabel` with a certain text and font will have a preferred size that is just large enough to display the whole text.

But when a component is displayed on the screen, then it may not be possible to show it with its *preferred* size (some reasons will be explained below). So when calling [`getSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize--), the method will return the *actual* size that the component *currently* has on the screen. When the containing frame is resized, then the component may also be resized, and then return a different value again.

(Note that `getSize()` basically returns a single object that contains the same values as those returned by `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`).

---

Why it is not always possible make sure that the *actual* size matches the *preferred* size:

The layout in Swing is usually handled by layout managers. The details are explained in the tutorial about [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), but I'll try to summarize the part that is relevant for this question here.

Such layout manager will *try* to lay out components with their preferred size. One can imagine that this is difficult, and sometimes impossible. Imagine a panel with a `GridLayout(1,2)` that contains two other panels:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |
|  Preferred Size:    |   Preferred Size    |
|     400 x 300       |      100 x 200      |
|                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

In the `GridLayout`, all components must have the same size. But their *preferred* sizes are different. So the layout manager simply **cannot** make sure that the *actual* sizes of the panels are the same as their *preferred* sizes. So it displays them with a size that is a compromise between the two. (It may also take into account the minimum and maximum size, making it even more difficult...). In the end, the size of both panels may, for example, be (300,200) pixels, even though the preferred sizes have been (400,300) and (100,200) pixels.

---

Specifically regarding the layout that you described: Note that `FlowLayout` is a bit special here. It will lay out the components with their preferred size, **if** there is enough space. If there is *not* enough space, then some components may not be visible. So you might try changing the `FlowLayout` in your rows to be a `GridLayout(1,n)`, where `n` is the number of keys in this row.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer.. I will defiantly read the to tutorial you attached to your response. About what you said ("changing the FlowLayout to be a GridLayout), Does this layout behaves differently than FlowLayout when there is not enough space for the components? In addition, can you assume why i don't get the paint i am trying? Should i call some container validate method?
When the application start i see only some of the keyboard, but all of them are mixed (e.g Tab and Shift are at the same line) and when i'm resizing the frame, also those keyboard disappear

Comment: @Eitanos30  The `GridLayout` will "force" the components to the size that is necessary to fit into the "grid cells" (so the components *might* be too small, but will still be visible). Regarding the validation etc.: This should usually not be necessary if you make sure to call `frame.setVisible(true)` **after** everything has been assembled. For more precise help on that, code might be necessary.

Comment: But I set a listener to JFrame resize, so each resize I need to calculate and set the buttons size. After the resizing which method should I call in order to refresh the keyboard buttons?

Comment: It should *not* be necessary to attach a listener for the resizing, and it should *not* be necessary to calculate and set the button sizes. This is *exactly* what will mess up your UI, because you're certainly not computing the same results as the layout managers. Just remove this part, and see whether you can achieve the desired layout *solely* relying on layout managers.

Comment: But what will make the button in a different size if i will use the gridLayout instead of using the FlowLayout with the calcaulation of buttons size?

Comment: In a `GridLayout`, all "grid cells" will have the same size. If you assign different sizes (by calling `key.setSize(...)`), things will be messed up. If you want components in one row to have different sizes, consider a horizontal `BoxLayout`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html . You can hire me for consulting, by the way.

Comment: @camickr Good to know (or bad...) (\*cough\* help-vampire...). Although this question initially wasn't in great shape, I had a quick look and didn't find one specifically about the `getPreferredSize` vs. `getSize` point, so I cleaned it up in the hope to make a somewhat "canonical" answer. But in the end, nothing can replace docs+tutorials and trying things out... :-/

Comment: @camickr, First of all thanks again. i Had already told you i'm appreciate your help in my first response. I don't know where you live but i'm living in a place where i need to serve in my country's army. When you are in army you don't have access to computer, so i tried to use the site by my phone. As you see i didn't response to any post i had post from last Monday. Now i see the message and immediately accepted it. But if you find it redundant to help me, so  don't help me anymore. This site is for helping people and not for getting a medal.Anyway, thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: @camickr You seem to be one of the newbies that have to be told: Stack Overflow is *not* a forum ;-P But seriously: One shouldn't immediately accept the first answer. Sometimes, it takes some time for better answers to show and bubble up. Beyond that, of course you're right with keeping a question on a single topic, and not request further and further fixes and extensions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The component's getWidth/getHeight return the current sizes. The getPreferredSize returns what the component would like to get. For example, a button with text will return a preferred size so the text will completely visible.

A reasonable layout manager will ask the child components for their preferred sizes and give them these sizes. This will result in preferred size for the parent component. If the parent component is set a smaller size, it can't enforce the child component's preferred sizes any more and either hides some or makes the components smaller.

Comment: Some references to the respective documentation would be nice

Comment: I hope it is what you meant:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getWidth()
and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()

Comment: @Thomas, I have some question that i am not sure i understood:
1.In which situation getWidth/Height will be with the same values as getPreferredSize.getWidth/Height?
2.Can you please explain me what you mean in:"if the parent component is set a smaller size,..it either hides some or makes the components smaller." Did you mean that child settled preferred size won't be the actual size? 
3.you said " This will result in preferred size for the parent component",so if parent size will be changed,doesn't it mean the parent container will be large enough to contain all his recalculated childs?

Comment: I have rewrite my post, so maybe it will make situation more clear

Comment: Unfortunately gridLayout can’t help me here because keys can have a different size. One can be 1.5,1.75,2 times bigger than the other. Therefore I was forced to use the flowLayod for each row in the keyboard