# Why is my JFrame size smaller than the size that I input into setPreferredSize()?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have tried running the following code. The GUI constructor that I call is from a class that extends `JPanel`.

As you can see I have already tried using the `pack()` method.

The window that appears is smaller than 500x500. How do I fix this?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main(){


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        setTitle("Chess");
        
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        setContentPane(gui);

        pack();

        setVisible(true);

    }



    public static void main(String[] args){

        Main main = new Main();
        main.repaint();
    }
```

Already tried using `pack()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the frame size includes the frame borders, title bars, and headers which are especially large and take up extra space.  Set the size of a `JPanel` and add that to the frame and draw and add components to the panel.  And don't forget to call `frame.pack()`.

Comment: also you should probably use setSize() instead as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone)

Comment: @GuyLawrence-Downs The default parent (`JFrame` in this case) layout manager is  `BorderLayout`  So `setPreferredSize` should be used.  In fact, it is customary to override `getPreferredsSize()` and have it return the size.

Comment: are they not talking about the size of the JFrame not the gui panel? I understand that reducing the size of the panel would also have the same affect.

Comment: I thought the OP was lamenting the fact that the frame did not have the space designated by the dimensions.